# Shortcut for git add --ignore-removal?

Tags: git

I have been typing `git add .` for years before commiting changes. From what I understand (from the message below) the modern equivalent would be `git add --ignore-removal <pathspec>` which is slightly more verbose. Is there a way to revert to the old behavior in the upcoming **version 2.0** of git or at least silence this message in the current version?

```
$ git add .
warning: You ran 'git add' with neither '-A (--all)' or '--ignore-removal',
whose behaviour will change in Git 2.0 with respect to paths you removed.
Paths like 'log/sunspot-solr-development.log.lck' that are
removed from your working tree are ignored with this version of Git.

* 'git add --ignore-removal <pathspec>', which is the current default,
  ignores paths you removed from your working tree.

* 'git add --all <pathspec>' will let you also record the removals.

Run 'git status' to check the paths you removed from your working tree.
```

Comment: I don't think there's any config for this, the man page just says that the default would become `-A`. You could alias something like `git a` to `git add --ignore-removal`.

Comment: Thanks Dogbert. I've added [alias] a = add . --ignore-removal to my .gitconfig

Comment: Why don't you request a shortcut option for `--ignore-removal` on git@vger.kernel.org?

Comment: I've been using `git add .` for years as well. Now getting these "warnings" and wondering if I'm using Git wrong?!? There must be hundreds of thousands of commits every day and there's no way people are typing out `git add --ignore-removal`. I'm not even sure what that means? Anyone know why they've made this change?

Comment: @Meltemi I have added an answer to explain the `--ignore-removal` option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The warning you see is from [commit ccc663b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ccc663bc24a3925b818df0ce97a5ba47e221f383), which refines [commit 45c45e3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/45c45e300bcbe493a39533bb04f6bd548e8a3f19).

That second commit does mention:

### `git add`: start preparing for "`git add <pathspec>...`" to default to "`-A`"

> **Plan to eventually make "git add" pretend as if "`-A`" is given when there is a pathspec on the command line**.
>
> For that transition to work, people need to learn either to say "`git add --no-all subdir/`" when they want to ignore the removed paths like "`subdir/z`", or to say "`git add -A subdir/`" when they want to take the state of the directory as a whole.
>
> "`git add`" without any argument will continue to be a no-op.

So the modern equivalent of `git add .` would actually be `git add -A .`: see "[How to make Git “`add --all`” by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19416195/6309)".

[Meltemi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/63761/meltemi) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16807584/shortcut-for-git-add-ignore-removal#comment24841398_16807584)

> I'm not even sure what that means? Anyone know why they've made this change?

The commit I mentioned above illustrates the `--ignore-removal` option:

> When "`git add subdir/`" is run without "`-u`" or "`-A`" option, e.g.

```
$ edit subdir/x
$ create subdir/y
$ rm subdir/z
$ git add subdir/
```

> **the command does not notice removal of paths (e.g. `subdir/z`) from the working tree**.
> This sometimes confuses new people, as arguably "`git add`" is told to record the current state of "`subdir/`" as a whole, not the current state of the paths that exist in the working tree that matches that pathspec (the latter by definition excludes the state of "`subdir/z`" because it does not exist in the working tree).