# How to make Git "add --all" by default?

Tags: git, alias, git-config

I just ran into this message:

```
$ git add .
warning: You ran 'git add' with neither '-A (--all)' or '--ignore-removal',
whose behaviour will change in Git 2.0 with respect to paths you removed.
Paths like 'README.md' that are
removed from your working tree are ignored with this version of Git.

* 'git add --ignore-removal <pathspec>', which is the current default,
  ignores paths you removed from your working tree.

* 'git add --all <pathspec>' will let you also record the removals.

Run 'git status' to check the paths you removed from your working tree.
```

I think setting `--all` is a pretty sane default, since I can `reset` if something was added unexpectedly. How can I make that behavior default?

Comment: `--all` does more than just add everything. It will also automatically add *removals* (e.g. you deleted a file for your working directory that was tracked in Git), which may not be what you want.

Comment: config options in "git config --help" doesn't show any option to add a default setting for the "git add" command

Comment: You can use [aliases](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Aliases) as an alternative

Comment: If you create a new file, add it unexpectedly, then reset to remove it from the index, the file will be deleted from your working copy. This is really inconvenient--it will force you to search through the object database for dangling objects. Better to not add everything by default.

Comment: @Yawar or, just don't add files that shouldn't be there?

Comment: @Lohoris - that's basically what I said :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The warning you see comes from [commit ccc663b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ccc663bc24a3925b818df0ce97a5ba47e221f383), itself reworking [commit 45c45e3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/45c45e300bcbe493a39533bb04f6bd548e8a3f19).

That second commit does include:

### `git add`: start preparing for "`git add <pathspec>...`" to default to "`-A`"

> **Plan to eventually make "git add" pretend as if "`-A`" is given when there is a pathspec on the command line**.
>   When resolving a conflict to remove a path, the current code tells you to "`git rm $path`", but with such a change, you will be able to say "git add $path" (of course you can do "git add -A $path" today).

So with Git 2.0, `git add .` will do what you want, but right now, a git alias is the way to get this by default.

```
git config alias.a 'add -A .'

[alias] 
  a = add -A .
```

---

This is now (March 2014) registered for the next release, with [commit 160c4b1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/160c4b183c6fe87417e1beb9a97949567bb3988a) and [commit fdc97ab](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fdc97abd4a8b04781356dc561b4ba5a634f9854f), for the next Git 2.0 (Q2 2014).

Comment: They added a big honking warning message about a future change in default behavior but no config option to say "make it the default now" (or "okay, I get it, stop bugging me")?  That seems sort've obnoxious.

Comment: @blahdiblah and 7 months later, it's still broken. Not a great move.

Answer (score 3):

With git you can create aliases, so you can try this:

```
git config --global alias.adall 'add . --all'
```

Here use "adall" but not "add" to avoid some unnecessary add but if you like add is also OK.

After this configuration then you can add all by command like below:

```
git adall
```

Comment: You need `--all` not `-all`.