# Always use git add --all

Tags: git

Sometimes when I want to `git add .` I get this message which is quite annoying:

```
warning: You ran 'git add' with neither '-A (--all)' or '--ignore-removal',
whose behaviour will change in Git 2.0 with respect to paths you removed.
Paths like 'demos/css/main.css' that are
removed from your working tree are ignored with this version of Git.

* 'git add --ignore-removal <pathspec>', which is the current default,
ignores paths you removed from your working tree.

* 'git add --all <pathspec>' will let you also record the removals.

Run 'git status' to check the paths you removed from your working tree.
```

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set an alias in your .bashrc file

something like:

```
alias ga='git add --all'
```

Answer (score 1):

`git add -A .` or alias something as in @TimRich's answer.  `git add .` is ambiguous in Git 2.0, and this is a warning.

Also check out [How to make Git "add --all" by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19416195/how-to-make-git-add-all-by-default)